# Embedded jetty with json/xml response

Tags: java, json, rest, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have embedded jetty server I want to create RESTful GET service which returns a pojo in XML/JSON format as response. can anyone give me one basic example how to write the handler for jetty? the example given only shows text type output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Jersey java REST framework (http://jersey.java.net/). The framework is easy to learn. You can use Object to Xml converter like JAXB to make your life easier.

Comment: but it doesn have any example for embedded server

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I had the same problem. 
I solved it by having a utility jar file that reads a properties file to configure contexts for Jersey Servlets, handlers, static files, exploded webapps etc in such a way that the resulting application jar configures the contexts automagically and is run from the command line.

Basically I have a HandlerCollection and successively add the servlets to it.

```
ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);
servletHolder.setInitParameter(
  "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", 
  clazz.getPackage().getName()
);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
  server, 
  "/some_path", 
  ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS
);
context.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/");
context.setHandler(handler);
handlers.addHandler(context);
```

Then I have an example Jersey servlet:

```
@Path("/user1")
public class JerseyResource1 {
  public JerseyResource1() {
  }
  @GET
  @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  public ExamplePojo getUser() {
    log.debug("Inside ExampleJerseyResource1 getUser()");
    ExamplePojo pojo = new ExamplePojo();
    pojo.setNumber(100);
    pojo.setWords("hello world 1");
    return pojo;
  }
```

}

The first calls gets a perf hit as Jersey configures stuff, but it works just peachy.

A junit test looks like this:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    Thread startupThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Starting Jetty...");
                JettyMain.main(new String[] {});
                // CHECKSTYLE_OFF: Because it does throw Exception!
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // CHECKSTYLE_ON
                System.err.println("Error Starting Jetty: " + ex);
            }
        }
    };
    startupThread.start();
    System.out.println("Waiting a few seconds to ensure Jetty is started");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Ok. Starting tests");
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
  ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
  Client client = Client.create(config);
  WebResource service = client.resource(
    UriBuilder.fromUri(
     "http://localhost:8080/admin/stop?secret=YourSecret"
     ).build());
    service.get(String.class);
    System.out.println("Sent stop command");
}

@Test
public void testJersey1() {
    System.out.println("Jersey1 returns correct 200 and body");
    ClientResponse response = getService(
      "http://localhost:8080/jersey1/user1/"
      ).get(ClientResponse.class);
    assertEquals("Response is 200", 200, response.getStatus());
    assertEquals(
      "Valid body", 
      "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>"
      + "<examplePojo><number>100</number><words>hello world 1</words></examplePojo>", 
      response.getEntity(String.class)
    );
    System.out.println("--> WORKED!");
}
```

CURL calls look like this:

```
# Show static public files folder:
curl -v http://localhost:8080/public/x.html
curl -v http://localhost:8080/public/x.txt
# Use baseline handlers:
curl -v http://localhost:8080/handler1/?url=hello
curl -v http://localhost:8080/handler2/?url=hello
# Use raw servlets with specific contexts:
curl -v http://localhost:8080/servlet1?url=hello
curl -v http://localhost:8080/servlet2?url=hello
# Call a Jersey servlet using default Accept header (xml):
curl -v http://localhost:8080/jersey1/user1/
curl -v http://localhost:8080/jersey2/user2/
# Request Jersey servlet but want JSON:
curl -v --header "Accept:application/json" http://localhost:8080/jersey1/user1/
# Use an exploded webapp:
curl -v http://localhost:8080/www/x.html
# Stop the server:
curl -v http://localhost:8080/admin/stop?secret=MySecret
```

Er... The following is not a plug. Seriously. It might be refused by the company...

I have a complete solution by which 1 jar file is added as a dependency and several tiny files (app.properties, classpath.sh, log4j.properties and run.sh) that completely configure a Jetty8 instance for numerous contexts, Handlers, Servlets, JerseyServlets, StaticFiles and ExplodedWebApps. The result is a self contained executable Jar that restarts, reloads, stops etc with almost zero effort. An added benefit is that it can act as a pseudo-classloader and avoids jar-hell. (A side effect is that mvn clean test works against it also)

If any one is interested, ping me and I can see if the company will allow me to OpenSource it and get it up on GitHub.
Or perhaps even document it via my own site http://www.randomactsofsentience.com

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI on embedded Jetty in general... I have created a github project that I humbly submit may cover most of the embedded jetty issues that keep cropping up. See https://github.com/ZenGirl/EmbeddedJettyRepository for details.

Answer (score 0):

Using a framework to handle the serialisation of JSON is the way to go.  However, here is a simple example:

```
public class MyServer extends AbstractHandler
{
    private static final int PORT = 8080;

    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().print("{ \"my_data\": \"Hello from Java!\" }");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(PORT);

        server.setHandler(new MeServer());
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Jetty started: http://localhost:" + PORT + "/");
        server.join();
    }
}
```