# How can I talk to MSMQ via HTTP?

Tags: c#, java, wcf, msmq

After 2 hrs of extensive googling I didn't find clear answer to following questions.

Is it possible to talk to MSMQ via HTTP ? If I understood it correctly it's possible starting from MSMQ 3.0 and it uses SOAP.

Are there **simple** samples of MSMQ client that sends message to MSMQ via HTTP ? Sample in C# will suffice.

I've seen blog-posts where people create WCF **service** that accepts message via HTTP and reroutes it to MSMQ but it's not what I want.

PS. My ultimate goal is to send message to MSMQ from Java code which is running under Jetty on linux machine. Therefore MSMQ/JNI bridges won't work for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Q: Is it possible to talk to MSMQ via HTTP?

A: Sure.  Lots of ways ;)

QUESTION:

Q) What is your environment?  COM/ActiveX?  Or can you use "more modern" message queueing?  What is your Windows version?  Is it a Windows client, or more of a server configuration?

Q) Assuming HTTP is in the mix, where is your web server?  On the MSMQ host?  Is it an IIS web server?  Or is Jetty the only HTTP part of the equation?

SUGGESTION:

If you had the luxury of web server on both sides; I'd just POST Json messages back and forth between the two environments (i.e. invent my own, small, REST-ful protocol).

IMHO...

Comment: I have linux machine with jetty server and I need to send message from Java code to MSMQ running on Windows Server 2008. Since I can't use native MSMQ protocol I thought perhaps I can compose SOAP message and shoot it directly.

Comment: You can.  But SOAP sucks ;)  If you insist, AXIS2 is probably your best bet, if you're not already familiar with it.  Personally, I think you'd probably have more fun yanking your fingernails out with a pair of pliers...

Comment: No no, I mean I have pre-existing requirement. I have MSMQ server to which I need to send messages. There is no choice about that for now.

Comment: 1) Here is a very simple C# example that uses MSMQ: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1119-sending-and-receiving-message-in-msmq-using-csharp.aspx.  2) Here is another very simple C# example for [Calling a JSON WebService from .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270464/best-way-to-call-a-json-webservice-from-a-net-console).  3) Finally, here's a thread on [Embedded Jetty with JSON/XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305186/embedded-jetty-with-json-xml-response).